# Android nullPointException during Typeface

Tags: android

I cannot understand where is the problem. I've insert this code:

```
String[] listOfText01 = {"R.id.text0101", "R.id.text0201"};

for (int cont = 0; cont < listOfText01.length; cont++) {
    int arrayTextID = getResources().getIdentifier(listOfText01[cont], "id", getString(R.string.packageName));
    TextView textLocation = (TextView) findViewById(arrayTextID);
    Typeface fontName = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
    textLocation.setTypeface(fontName);
}
```

but at row

```
    Typeface fontName = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
```

return a nullPointerException. What's happen? This was working fine before to set the FOR CICLE but now I dont understand what's happen. Someone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: post your logcat then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String[] listOfText01 = {"text0101", "text0201"};

try{
  for (int cont = 0; cont < listOfText01.length; cont++) {
      int arrayTextID = getResources().getIdentifier(listOfText01[cont], "id", getPackageName());
      TextView textLocation = (TextView) findViewById(arrayTextID);
      Typeface fontName = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
      textLocation.setTypeface(fontName);
  }
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```